# Is it possible to use the jquery validator in TinyMCE?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, tinymce-5

I'm trying to use jQuery no validator in a form that has a textarea using TinyMCE and I can't leave it as required.

I found some examples to make this requirement, but everyone I add ends up removing TinyMCE from my textarea.

Can anyone can help me? all examples are always giving error.

This is my code:

```
@model Contato
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contato nos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var end = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d14635.842857905212!2d-47.446606835918516!3d-23.49792447583607!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94cf61e82bba04e5%3A0xec1214319ddea74d!2sMarcenaria%20MF!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1620093541821!5m2!1spt-BR!2sbr";
}


<!-- ======= Breadcrumbs ======= -->
<section id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h2>Contato</h2>
            <ol>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Marcenaria MF</a></li>
                <li>Contato</li>
            </ol>
        </div>

    </div>
</section><!-- End Breadcrumbs -->
<!-- ======= Contact Section ======= -->
<div class="map-section">
    <iframe style="border:0; width: 100%; height: 350px;" src=@end frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<section id="contact" class="contact">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up">

            <div class="col-lg-10">

                <div class="info-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 info">
                            <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i>
                            <h4>Endereço:</h4>
                            <p> R. Yashica, N° 350 - Jardim Bela Vista,<br>Sorocaba - SP, 18016-440</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 info mt-4 mt-lg-0">
                            <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
                            <h4>Email:</h4>
                            <p>info@example.com<br>contact@example.com</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 info mt-4 mt-lg-0">
                            <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
                            <h4>Telefones:</h4>
                            <p>(15) 99756-6839<br>(15) 99761-6833</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form id="form_contato" asp-controller="Contatos" asp-action="Contato" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="Nome" class="form-control" asp-for="Nome" placeholder="Seu Nome">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" asp-for="Email" placeholder="Seu Email">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Assunto" asp-for="Assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Assunto" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="Mensagem" rows="5" asp-for="Mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Mensagem" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-3">
                        <div class="loading" id="loading">Loading</div>
                        <div class="error-message" id="error-message"></div>
                        <div class="sent-message" id="sent-message">Sua mensagem foi enviada. Obrigado!</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Enviar Mensagem</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</section><!-- End Contact Section -->

<script src="~/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/tinymce/langs/pt_BR.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            height: 250,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: 'link, autolink link, textcolor, paste',
            toolbar: false,
            content_css: '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css',
            language: 'pt_BR',
            paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: false,
            paste_block_drop: false,
            paste_data_images: false,
            paste_as_text: true,
            paste_enable_default_filters: false,
            paste_webkit_styles: "none",
            browser_spellcheck: true,
            contextmenu: true,
            branding: false,
            statusbar: false,
            setup: function (ed) {
                //On change call
                ed.on('change', function (e) {
                    //Validate tinyMCE on text change
                    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                    $("#" + ed.id).valid();
                }

                );
            },
        });


        $(function () {

            $.validator.setDefaults({
                submitHandler: function () {
                    $('#loading').addClass('d-block');
                }
            });
            var content = tinyMCE.get("Mensagem");

            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            //initialize validatoe
            var validator = $("#form_contato").submit(function () {

                // update underlying textarea before submit validation
               
                alert($("#Mensagem").val());

            }).validate({
                ignore: ".ignore",
                rules:
                {
                    Email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                    },
                    Nome: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    Assunto: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    Mensagem: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                },
                errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
                    // position error label after generated textarea
                    if (element.is("textarea")) {
                        label.insertAfter(element.next());
                    } else {
                        label.insertAfter(element)
                    }
                }
            });

            validator.focusInvalid = function () {
                // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
                if (this.settings.focusInvalid) {
                    try {
                        var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
                        if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
                            tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("#Mensagem")).focus();
                        } else {
                            toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
                    }
                }
            }

          
        })

    });
</script>


@if (ViewData["MSG"] != null)
{
    <script>
      alert(@ViewData["MSG"].ToString());
    </script>
}
```

I really appreciate your help guys

Comment: Do you want to make textarea optional?

Comment: Hi Ali Bhutta, I would like to leave it to fill, however it does not stay when I use tinymce, it allows subimit with it blank